# Docker Wordpress tar: <file> Cannot change ownership to uid 33, gid 33: Operation not permitted

Tags: wordpress, macos, docker, apache2

I have created a docker-compose file for local development using Wordpress, and I've finally got NFS working (normal volume mount was too slow, because of Docker / Mac issues).

Except I'm running into a new issue, all files in the NFS share (which is the wp_content folder) give such error:

```
tar: ./wp-content/themes/twentynineteen/archive.php: 
Cannot change ownership to uid 33, gid 33: Operation not permitted
```

I've found this issue https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/issues/137 in which they refer to https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/pull/249, but I still can't get it working. Wondering if anyone can help me out, this is my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  wordpress:
    image: wordpress:latest
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - nfsmount:/var/www/html/wp-content
      - ./.htaccess:/var/www/html/.htaccess:cached
      - ./wp-data/wp-config.php:/var/www/html/wp-config.php:cached
      - ./logs/debug.log:/var/www/html/wp-content/debug.log
    environment:
      APACHE_RUN_USER: www-data
      APACHE_RUN_GROUP: www-data

volumes:
  nfsmount:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: nfs
      o: addr=host.docker.internal,rw,nolock,hard,nointr,nfsvers=3
      device: ":/Users/myuser/Sites/dockertest/wp-data/wp-content"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error is reported by tar command that try to change owner.

In order to avoid tar to set owner you can set variable `TAR_OPTIONS` to `--no-same-owner`
From [tar manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tar.1.html):

> --no-same-owner
>             Extract files as yourself (default for ordinary users).

You can add this in your docker-compose file with :

```
  TAR_OPTIONS: --no-same-owner
```

Comment: Here you go, you helped me big time. Unfortunately I was a bit delayed to reward the bounty, so I just added another bounty of 100 before accepting your answer. The TAR_OPTIONS environment variable did the trick, docker-compose returned a "Complete! Wordpress has been succesfully copied to /var/www/html" without any errors.

Comment: I just see I have to award the bounty separately and I can award the new bounty in 23 hours, so I will do it tomorrow ;)

Comment: @ErikvandeVen: Thanks, I found this building some dockers that use root and have no user corresponding to the original tar.

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you are having is that you are mounting a local volume with your user's permissions, and not `www-data`. As such, `www-data` is not able to change the permissions of files that your user owns. To fix it, you should be able to do `chown 33:33 -R /Users/myuser/Sites/dockertest/wp-data/wp-content`. Keep in mind that if you get and error something like `Permissions denied`, run the command with `sudo`.

Comment: I know the permissions are the issue, but I need a solution with my docker instance. The links I provided already seem to show a solution for this problem, the thing is that they don't show it how to configure a docker-compose file with those settings. I can't just change the owner of my local folder because docker has to be able to reach it with its internal user

Comment: As far as I know, you can not change file permissions in a docker-compose file with out changing the user id on disk

Comment: But if you think about it, it does not make quite sense to change the owner of my own folder, with my own files, to a Docker user, just so it can access it. At least I must be able to have a common user or whatever, so I can still access my own files, and so can docker.

Comment: You could change only the uid of the file and leave the gid the same which should still allow you to access your files, but also allow docker to access them as well.

Answer (score 0):

First, you could try setting the additional volume option of *nocopy* to *True*.

If that doesn't work maybe you check the groups *www-data* is part of.
I think in case you want to set the user and group to *www-data*, ensure *www-data* is part of the same group as the nfs shared folder.

Else it is preferred to use a local user and group that has access to the nfs file.

```
APACHE_RUN_USER  : local_user
APACHE_RUN_GROUP : local_group
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to  `services.wordpress.environment`:

```
TAR_OPTIONS: "--owner=www-data"
```